# json object to javascript global reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I have ajax which calls json, i wanted to have this json object a javascript global reference so that I can use this reference to access json object. here is code.

```
var jsonData;

$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
 jsonData = json; /*i wanted to pass this json object to global reference*/
});
nextAlbum function(){
    console.log(jsonData.albums.length); /*I have to acces here*/
}
```

your help will be appreciated.
here is my latest code.

```
var mysplitSlider = (function(){
var init, findTotalAlbums, countAlbum;
var jsonData;

return{
    init: function(url){
        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
            jsonData = json;
        });
    },
    nextAlbum:function(){
        console.log(jsonData.albums.length);
    },
    previousAlbum:function(){}
};
```

})();

var url = "assets/images/detail_view_gallery/data.json";

mysplitSlider.init(url);

please help me so that I can access reference variable/object for json.

Comment: isn't this code working as expected, any errors u getting?

Comment: `nextAlbum function() {...` is a syntax error.

Comment: what's the output of this console.log(jsonData.albums.length);

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, then you're running into problems with the asynchronous nature of `getJSON`.

Since `getJSON` is *asynchronous* your `jsonData` variable will not contain any data until that asynchronous call has received a response and executed the callback. If you attempt to access `jsonData` before that's happened, you'll likely run into errors.

You will need to move any code that relies upon `jsonData` into the callback function.

---

Note, the above assumes your syntax errors are just a result of creating the question and are not part of your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Modified code: `jsonData` would not be available immediately since `getJSON` is a asynchronous call.   and your function `nextAlbum`  definition was not currect.

```
  var jsonData ;
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
 nextAlbum (json);
 jsonData = json; /*i wanted to pass this json object to global reference*/
});
function nextAlbum (json){
    console.log(json.albums.length); /*I have to acces here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, AJAX is *Asynchronous* JavaScript And XML...

```
function nextAlbum(jsonData){
    console.log(jsonData.albums.length);
    /* If you want, add a global var to save json */
}

$.getJSON(url, nextAlbum);
```